# Specifying a callback function in preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex

I have some code like this (this is a simplified example):

```
function callback_func($matches) {
  return $matches[0] . "some other stuff";
}

function other_func($text) {
  $out = "<li>"; 
  preg_replace_callback("/_[a-zA-Z]*/","callback_func",$desc);
  $out .= $desc ."</li> \r\n";
  return $out;
}

echo other_func("This is a _test");
```

The output of this should be

```
<li>This is a _testsome other stuff</li>
```

but I just get

```
<li>This is a _test</li>
```

What am I doing wrong/what bizarre incantation is required to appease the php gods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`preg_replace_callback` does not modify the string in place, but instead returns a modified copy of it.  Try the following instread:

```
function other_func($text) {
    $out = "<li>"; 
    $out .= preg_replace_callback("/_[a-zA-Z]*/","callback_func",$desc);
    $out .= "</li> \r\n";
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Oops, should have refreshed. Figured it out just after you did. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're never appending the output from the function into the $out variable. So in callback_func() you have to use:

```
$out .= $matches[0] . "some other stuff";
```

Then it will add the result into the string for you to output. As it is, you're just returning a value and doing nothing with it.

Comment: You're mixing scopes.  `$out` is in `other_func` but `$matches` is in `callback_func`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. preg_replace_callback doesn't modify the original subject, which I assumed it did. I had to change

```
preg_replace_callback("/_[a-zA-Z]*/","callback_func",$desc);
```

to

```
$desc = preg_replace_callback("/_[a-zA-Z]*/","callback_func",$desc);
```